# line botのエラーを解消したい。

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

GASでline　botを作成したのですが、うまく動きません。

```
//キャッシュを削除する。
if (userMessage.test(clearExp)) {
    replyChatprivate(replyToken, "キャンセルしました。");
  cleardata(userID);
 }
function cleardata(userID) {
  const keys = [userID];
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    keys.push(userID + i);
    deletecache(keys[i]);
  }
}
function deletecache(key) {
  const cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
  cache.remove(key);
}
```

このプログラムのどこかに問題があるはずです。
なぜか、コメントアウトしないと動きません。

コードは以下のサイトにあります。
https://github.com/asdfgh-13/gas/blob/master/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89.gs

どこに誤りがあるのか教えて頂けないでしょうか？

Comment: ソースコードの量が多く、しかも外部リンクで、さらには質問者さんが全くわからないだとなかなか回答が付きづらい印象です。このサイトでは[再現可能な短いサンプルコード](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)の掲載を推奨しています。いったん最低限の機能だけを備えたものを作ってみてそれを試してみて、状況の切り分けをして質問を精査するとより回答が得やすいと思います。

Comment: そこまでコードは多くないと思うのですが。また、コードを減らしても半分程度にしかなりませんし。

Comment: 回答者の立場からすると、「まったく動かない」ということでコードを見てみようと思うと、複数の機能が実装されていてどこから読めば良いのだろう、という気持ちになりました。コードがこれより短くできそうにないなら、具体的に動いていない部分について期待する動作と実際の動作の説明をしていただけると回答しやすいです。もしどの機能も期待するように動かないという訳であれば、機能を減らしてミニマムな動作のみするコードで試してみると質問者さんもデバッグしやすいかと思います。

Comment: すくなくとも、`const userID = json.sorce.userId;` と `const Groupid = json.sorce.groupId;` の `sorce` は `source` で、`const replayToken = json.replayToken;` の `json.replayToken` は `json.replyToken` でしょう。

Comment: コメント欄では改行が使えないのでプログラムの説明には不向きです。質問文は後からでも [edit] できるので、直接追記してみてください。

Comment: metropolisさん、cubick♦さんありがとうございます。

Comment: 今後のことを考えるとデバッグ方法を再検討したほうがいいかもしれないですね。ソースチェックか動作検証でしかデバックできないとなるとなかなかつらい印象です。できればステップ実行できるようなデバッガがあると簡単に解決しそうですが、、

Comment: いい方法を知りませんか？